# Not getting any data from CURL Authorization

Tags: php

I need to get all surveys through api call. The api provider give me this

```
Example curl Authorization:
    curl –header “Content-Type: application/json” --header “Authorization: Basic 
    “API_KEY””-X GET “url”
```

I have set curl code like this

```
$access = 'apikey';
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic'.$access
);
$url = 'url';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);  
print_r($result);
```

But not getting any data. Can anyone please advise me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the same using CURL?

Comment: make sure your server has enabled php_curl extesion. if its enable then what is the result of print_r($result)

Comment: `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` is your friend

Comment: also need to have a space for `'Authorization: Basic<space>'.$access`

Comment: I am trying the code on localhost. Do i need to try this on server?

Comment: Hello codekaizer,

When i have set CURLOPT_VERBOSE, I am getting this error

Fatal error: Call to undefined function url_setopt() in